# Question about pronunciation in British accent (Modern RP)

Tags: british-english, conversation, contemporary-english, received-pronunciation

In the British accent (Modern RP), the word "often" is pronounced as "ɒf.tən" with the "t" sound. What about words like "soften", "fasten", and "moisten"? Should I pronounce those words with the "t" sound in Modern RP?

Comment: [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/often) and [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/often) dictionaries in their pronunciation recordings both have a generic educated southern English accent close to some forms of modern RP. Is this the sort of accent you want? Have you listened to the recordings? Have you looked up pronunciation values in other dictionaries?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this is a matter of experience and - to some extent - opinion. It probably depends most on social or regional background of the speaker.

My experience in Britain is that “often” is variously heard with or without the “t” sound; it is sometimes heard with a short “o” and sometimes with the sound of “or”. None of these is exclusively “correct”; all are acceptable. The short “o” is probably more heard in the north of Britain.

In my experience the “t” in the other words is usually not heard, or is present only in vestigial and barely perceptibly form.

Others may have different social or regional backgrounds that give them another perspective on the question. Anyone who asserts that a particular pronunciation is “correct” is likely to be too influenced by their personal background.

Comment: Since the OP has specifically inquired about the pronunciation in RP, I think there is a "correct" answer.

Comment: Is there any accent in which the *t* is pronounced in "soften", "fasten", and "moisten"?

Comment: None of the dictionaries I've checked suggest a /t/ in soften, fasten, or moisten. Often is given with both pronunciations in Cambridge and only without a /t/ in Macmillan 
 and Collins. (I'd rather not use the term RP which covers a multitude of accents from the bizarrely affected to the "standard middle-class SE English" such as you'll find in dictionaries.)